# Load controllers dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set up an angular application that will load controllers dynamically according to the route. I am following this [tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs), but I can't get it to work. I also made some small modifications to the tutorial code that suit me, but I don't think they are the problem.

I have put almost all of my code-flow here, so if you want to skip it, the errors are in the last snippets.

Note: I have changed the code snippets as I progressed.

**index.html** base file *(I removed the ng-app and ng-controller parameters, as I realized that I call them manually with RequireJS)*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Little Buddha</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/libs/requirejs/require.js" data-main="app/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I am using RequireJS to load all scripts dynamically. Here's the **main.js** configuration file:
*(I also edited this file, adding angular and ngRoute to the shim config)*

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '',
    urlArgs: 'dev=' + new Date().getTime(),
    paths: {
        'angular' : '/assets/libs/angular/angular.min',
        'ngRoute' : '/assets/libs/angular-route/angular-route.min',
        'routeResolver' : '/app/routeResolver',
        'app' : '/app/app',
        'constants' : '/app/global/constants',
        'AuthService' : '/app/global/AuthService',
        'AppController' : '/app/global/AppController',
    },
    shim: {
        'angular' : {
            exports : 'angular',
        },
        'ngRoute' : {
            deps : ['angular'],
        },
    }
});

require(
    [
        'ngRoute',
        'app',
        'routeResolver',
        'constants',
        'AppController',
        'AuthService',
    ],
    function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['littleBuddha']);
    }
);
```

**routeResolver.js**

```
'use strict';

define([], function () {

    var routeResolver = function () {

        this.$get = function () {
            return this;
        };

        this.route = function () {

            var resolve = function (baseName, path, secure) {
                if (!path) path = '';

                var routeDef = {};
                routeDef.templateUrl = path + baseName + '.html';
                routeDef.controller = baseName + 'Controller';
                routeDef.secure = (secure) ? secure : false;
                routeDef.resolve = {
                    load: ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
                        var dependencies = [path + baseName + 'Controller.js'];
                        return resolveDependencies($q, $rootScope, dependencies);
                    }]
                };

                return routeDef;
            },

            resolveDependencies = function ($q, $rootScope, dependencies) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                require(dependencies, function () {
                    defer.resolve();
                    $rootScope.$apply()
                });

                return defer.promise;
            };

            return {
                resolve: resolve
            }
        };

    };

    var servicesApp = angular.module('routeResolverServices', []);

    //Must be a provider since it will be injected into module.config()    
    servicesApp.provider('routeResolver', routeResolver);
});
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

define(['routeResolver'], function () {

    var app = angular.module('littleBuddha', ['routeResolverServices']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', 'routeResolverProvider', '$controllerProvider', 
                '$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide',
        function ($routeProvider, routeResolverProvider, $controllerProvider, 
                  $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide) {

            console.log('test');

            app.register =
            {
                controller: $controllerProvider.register,
                directive: $compileProvider.directive,
                filter: $filterProvider.register,
                factory: $provide.factory,
                service: $provide.service
            };

            var route = routeResolverProvider.route;

            $routeProvider
                .when('/login', route.resolve('Login', '/app/components/login/'))
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });

        }
    ]);

    return app;
});
```

And finally, **AppController.js**:

```
'use strict';

define(['app'], function (app) {

    //This controller retrieves data from the customersService and associates it with the $scope
    //The $scope is ultimately bound to the customers view due to convention followed by the routeResolver

    app.register.controller('AppController', function ($scope, USER_ROLES, AuthService) {

        $scope.currentUser = null;
        $scope.userRoles = USER_ROLES;
        $scope.isAuthorized = AuthService.isAuthorized;

        $scope.setCurrentUser = function (user) {
            $scope.currentUser = user;
        };

    });

    return app;

});
```

**EDIT**

So, now I have located the problem. In **app.js**, app.config function is never called, so the register parameters are never applied and the routes are never computed. Actually, that `console.log('test')` is never printed.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are not initializing the route in routeResolver.

Notice in the tutorial they run the routeResolver immediately with their routeConfig. I can not see where you initialize the this.route function.

From the tutorial:

```
    this.route = function (routeConfig) {

        var resolve = function (baseName, path, secure) {
                if (!path) path = '';

                var routeDef = {};
                routeDef.templateUrl = routeConfig.getViewsDirectory() + path + baseName + '.html';
                routeDef.controller = baseName + 'Controller';
                routeDef.secure = (secure) ? secure : false;
                routeDef.resolve = {
                    load: ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
                        var dependencies = [routeConfig.getControllersDirectory() + path + baseName + 'Controller.js'];
                        return resolveDependencies($q, $rootScope, dependencies);
                    }]
                };

                return routeDef;
            },

            resolveDependencies = function ($q, $rootScope, dependencies) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                require(dependencies, function () {
                    defer.resolve();
                    $rootScope.$apply()
                });

                return defer.promise;
            };

        return {
            resolve: resolve
        }
    }(this.routeConfig);
```

Yours:

```
    this.route = function (routeConfig) {

        var resolve = function (baseName, path, secure) {
            if (!path) path = '';

            var routeDef = {};
            routeDef.templateUrl = path + baseName + '.html';
            routeDef.controller = baseName + 'Controller';
            routeDef.secure = (secure) ? secure : false;
            routeDef.resolve = {
                load: ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
                    var dependencies = [path + baseName + 'Controller.js'];
                    return resolveDependencies($q, $rootScope, dependencies);
                }]
            };

            return routeDef;
        },

        resolveDependencies = function ($q, $rootScope, dependencies) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            require(dependencies, function () {
                defer.resolve();
                $rootScope.$apply()
            });

            return defer.promise;
        };

        return {
            resolve: resolve
        }
    };
```

Notice in yours that this function is not executed.

So I think you need to run this function with a routeConfig object to get it defined and working.

EDIT: even if you don't want a routeConfig object (which seems to be your aim) you still need to run the function with no parameter passed.

Last ideas from me:

Sorry I can't be more help. I will try 2 more suggestions and thats me out i'm afraid.

You say app.config is never called. That might be something to do with load order. Try this in your main.js.

```
require(
    [
        'ngRoute',
        'app',
        'routeResolver',
        'constants',
        'AppController',
        'AuthService',
    ],
    function () {
      angular.element(document).ready(function() {
          angular.bootstrap(document, ['littleBuddha']);
      });
    }
);
```

OR, it never gets called because the line

```
define(['routeResolver'], function () {
```

Means that it tries to load routeResolver first. If there is some exception in routeResolver then it will fail hitting the function to setup app at all. In which case I would suggest debugging through to see how far you actually get through routeResolver.js on load.

Thats me out of ideas, when i'm stuck like that, i usually start by getting a version working *exactly* like the demo and then work backwards to what I actually want step by step to see when it stops working.

Good luck, sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Well actually in the tutorial they used that command to call the routeConfig function and set the paths inside. **this.route** is called in the **app.js** file afterwards with the command `var route = routeResolverProvider.route;` and `$routeProvider.when('/login', route.resolve('Login', '/app/components/login/'))` call. Anyway, I tried your solution and nothing changes.

Comment: Still seems to me that the this.route should be initialized immediately when it is declared, there is also now no need for the function to take routeConfig. Update the code in your question to what you are now using, and maybe consider making a plunkr for demo and editing.

Comment: I updated my question. However, as a php developer this is all new for me and it becomes quite complex. Even if I get it to work, I don't think I will fully understand why. I think I will try all over again with ocLazyLoad, seems much more intuitive. https://oclazyload.readme.io/v1.0

Comment: I updated again and again, until I found the problem. Now I know where it is, but I don't know how to solve it...